# LL1 grammar in compiling

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

I have a question about LL1 grammar. If we have grammar like this:

```
<S>::=<A>
<A>::=<A> car cat | epsilon
```

What is the First `<A>` can be? Is it just epsilon? And if its just epsilon, then the language could not be LL1! I am confused...

Answer (score 0):

```
 First(A) = {epsilon, car}
```

If A is a non-terminal and A : a α is a production, then
add a to First( A ). If A : epsilon is a production, then add epsilon
to First( A ).

If A : α1 α2 α3 ... αm is a production, add First( α1 ) to
First( A ). If α1 derives epsilon, add First( α2 ) to First( A ). If
both α1 and α2 derive epsilon, add First( α3 ) to First( A ),
and so on.